# database design for simple comment

Tags: sql-server, mysql, database-design

I have a following given scenario. 
A user can have zero or more item. 
A user can comment on the item. (Just simple comment listing with name of people who comment, no need hierarchical structure for replying comment)

And i come out database structure like this. Not sure if this is a good database design

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You design is basic and cover

```
1 user -> many items
1 item -> many comments
1 user -> many comments
```

The question is would you like the user to be able to comment on the same item multiple of times?
if yes, you do have a good design else we would need to work on it.

Comment: well, ya. a user should be able to comment on the same item multiple of times. However, i would appreciate if you could provide design for the case where a user only can comment on same item one time in database level

Comment: Change the User - > Comments from 1 - Many to 1-1